# The update command is not working in composer for a xeroAPI in github

Tags: php, api, github, cakephp, composer-php

I have cake4 project with xeroapi php 2.1.7 from github https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2 . Everything works fine with my xero connection through cakephp4.

I upgrade the xeroapi to the latest 2.17 (dont confuse with my current 2.1.7) with

```
       composer update xeroapi/xero-php-oauth2
```

That worked NO ERRORS but it says nothing to Install and i checked the files and nothing has been updated? Nothing to Install,Update or remove. There is no lock file .

Here is my json file. I dont see anything to change here in the json file either?

```
{
    "name": "xeroapi/xero-php-oauth2",
    "description": "Xero official PHP SDK for oAuth2 generated with OpenAPI spec 3",
    "keywords": [
        "openapispec",
        "xero",
        "php",
        "sdk",
        "rest",
        "api"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/xeroapi/xero-php-oauth2",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Xero API Team",
            "homepage": "https://developer.xero.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2 | ^7.0",
        "league/oauth2-client": "^2.5.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.6",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.12"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "XeroAPI\\XeroPHP\\" : "lib/" }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "XeroAPI\\XeroPHP\\" : "test/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the xeroapi's composer file, not yours.

Comment: yes that is correct and you have a solution?

Comment: Well, how about we start with you showing actually _your_ `composer.json` file, so that we can get an idea of what might possibly be wrong in there?

Comment: didnt i do this?

Comment: No, that is the composer file that belongs to the XeroAPI library, _your_ composer file lives in your application's root folder, and would require the XeroAPI library accordingly.

Comment: it is from composer.json in the root application folder so isnt this what you are wanting?

Comment: If that is from your application's root, then you've broken your composer file, possibly even your dependencies if an update was run using that file. This is what the default CakePHP app template composer file looks like: **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.x/composer.json**. If you're using version control, revert the changes that overwrote that file, otherwise manually recreate whatever you had before.

Comment: i havent touched the file (computer generated) so not sure what to add